# Query to get worksheet manager hierarchy for a parameter in BI-publisher

Tags: sql, bi-publisher

The parameter has two values direct reports and indirect report.

I have tried:

```
 select distinct cch.emp_person_id,
        cch.lvl_num Empl_Lvl,
        cch_lv.lvl_num MGR_LVL
 from cmp_cwb_hrchy cch, cmp_cwb_hrchy cch_lv
 where cch.mgr_person_id = :Mgr_id and
       cch_lv.emp_person_id = :Mgr_id and
       cch.MGR_PERSON_EVENT_ID= cch_lv.MGR_PERSON_EVENT_ID and 
       cch.EMP_PERSON_EVENT_ID = cch_lv.EMP_PERSON_EVENT_ID and
       cch.lvl_num = cch_lv.lvl_num and
       ( 1=1 and cch.lvl_num = case when :direct_ALL = 'Direct' then cch_lv.lvl_num+1 else NULL end) and
       ( 1=1 and cch.lvl_num > case when :direct_ALL = 'ALL' then cch_.lvl_num else NULL end)
```

Comment: Could you post the what have you tried?

Comment: sorry. i am blank.i am searching in cmp_cwb_hrchy table and also cmp_cwb_person_info

Comment: The code gets unreadable when posted in a comment. Please [edit] your question to add details, don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Copied request from comment to question, formatted title.

Comment: sorry everyone a small change. In cmp_cwb_hrchy table, for each manager or employee there will be lvl_num 0,1,2,3 etc. so i have to pick employees list if we pass manager_id. i.e if mgr_id=123456789 then his direct reports will be lvl_num=1. else i want display all workers just by passing manager_id.

Comment: now it will be easy...so can you help me to write decode or case statment for this

Comment: select cch.emp_person_id 
from cmp_cwb_hrchy cch, cmp_cwb_person_info ccpi
where ccpi.WS_MGR_PERSON_EVENT_ID=cch.MGR_PERSON_EVENT_ID
and ccpi.PERSON_EVENT_ID=cch.EMP_PERSON_EVENT_ID
and decode(:mgr_id,

Comment: now i want to add decode or case for this..if :mgr_id value is passed then lvl_num=1(all direct reports are displayed) else all workers value should be passed.